# LoRa point-to-point communication

Tags: esp32, lora, lorawan

I would like to create a point-to-point connection between a LoRa temperature sensor and a M5 Stack (ESP32) with LoRa module. However, I am a beginner with LoRa, so I have a few questions:

Are all packets send with LoRa (not LoRaWAN) encrypted? Or does it depend on the producer of the LoRa sensor?
Can the content of the packet received by the M5 Stack be viewed? (If I understand correctly, with the LoRaWAN the content can only be viewed after it is on the server).
Can I send measured temperatures from multiple LoRa sensors to one M5 Stack? If yes, how could I distinguish from which sensor the packet has been sent?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw LoRa is just about sending raw data using the LoRa modulation. There's no encryption, there are no acks, no counters, no device identifiers, nothing. All of this, happens in upper layers, usually the LoRaWAN layer.

If you want encryption on a raw LoRa link, unless the providers of the LoRa modules have added <del>they</del> their own, you'll have to do it yourself, with all the associated caveats (it's harder than you think, as was shown by [WEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Weak_security), though the levels of traffic on a LoRa link make some of the attacks on WEP unlikely).

In LoRaWAN encryption indeed happens between the end device and the LNS (network server).

If you use raw LoRa without encryption, you will most definitely be able to read any data sent by the end devices

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So if I understand correctly, there are, however, device identifiers with LoRaWAN? Could the packets sent by a LoRaWAN sensor be received and pushed to a database by a M5stack with a LoRa module (and decrypted using Cloud functions) or is a LNS necessary?

Comment: Yes, LoRaWAN devices all have identifiers. Decryption happens at the LNS, so either you have to embark an LNS on the ESP32 (no idea if this is possible or if there are any implementations of that), or everything would be terminated at the LNS and then the data sent back to the ESP32. The alternative is to build your own protocol on top of LoRa, with identifiers, encryption, etc. Not knowing more details about your use case it’s difficult to say which option would be best.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I posted a new question after your answer. If you would like to take a look here is the link: https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/sending-lora-packets-using-lorawan-sensor-device